# Why does MongoDB ignore the value when it's read from a variable but not when it's inputted directly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've very weird problem with mongodb used with node.js. My collection `channels` looks that:

```
[
    {
        name: "Main",
        is_global: true
    },
    {
        name: "Another one",
        is_global: false,
        owner: 472,
        ops: [],
        subscriptions: [472]
    }

]
```

I want to get all object where `is_global` is true, or in subscriptions is user's id. I'm using function:

```
var findChannels = function(db, user_id, callback) {
    debug("Get for id %s", user_id); // "Get for id 472"

    var cursor = db.collection('channels').find({ $or: [ { "is_global":true}, {"subscriptions" : user_id} ] } );
    var output = [];
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc != null) {
            output.push(doc);
        } else {
            callback(output);
        }
    });
};
```

I don't know why I'm getting just the first object (with `is_global` as true), without the second one. Moreover, when I set user's id directly in function, everything works fine, why?

```
var cursor = db.collection('channels').find({ $or: [ { "is_global":true}, {"subscriptions" : user_id} ] } );
// Returns just one
var cursor = db.collection('channels').find({ $or: [ { "is_global":true}, {"subscriptions" : 472} ] } );
// Returns two
```

Comment: You really should implement some logging in your code. Certainly the `user_id` value is not actually what you expect. Odds are on since this is the "basic driver" that the `req` param is actually a "string", as all request parameters just are unless you explicitly "cast" them otherwise.

Comment: But `user_id` value is correct. I check that even in function (`debug`).

Comment: Read what I said again. It's likely a "string." Use `parseInt(user_id)` to make sure it goes though to the query as a "numeric value"

Comment: Argh, you're right. Now everything works fine.

Comment: As I said, *"Request parameters are **always** strings"*. The only exception is if you have some "middleware" that parses a "request body". But that is basically different to request paramters themselves.